# Oauth2 redirection to invalid port 8080

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

My requirement is i need add image signature to the Gmail users dynamically.

FYI: The following is the process i followed

1. created project in google console
2. created Oauth Client ID in the following way

   Application Type: web

   Authorised JavaScript origins: http://localhost

   Authorised redirect URIs: http://localhost:3000
3. downloaded as client_request.json

The code is given below

'''

```
 from apiclient import discovery

 from googleapiclient.discovery import build
 from googleapiclient import discovery
 from httplib2 import Http
 from oauth2client import file, client, tools
 from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
 args = argparser.parse_args()
 from oauth2client.file import Storage
 SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'
 STORAGE = Storage('credentials.storage')
 credentials = STORAGE.get()
 creds =None
 args.noauth_local_webserver = True
 http = httplib2.Http()
 if not creds or creds.invalid:
   flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
   creds = tools.run_flow(flow, STORAGE,http=http)
 GMAIL = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
 addresses = GMAIL.users().settings().sendAs().list(userId='me',
    fields='sendAs(isPrimary,sendAsEmail)').execute().get('sendAs')
for address in addresses:
 if address.get('isPrimary'):
    break
signature = {'signature':'<img src="https://server:8000/test.png" alt="asaa" width="100" height="100">'}

 rsp = GMAIL.users().settings().sendAs().patch(userId='me',
    sendAsEmail=address['sendAsEmail'], body=signature).execute()
 print("Signature changed to '%s'" % rsp['signature']) '''
```

**I am stuck with 2 issues:**

**1) After i run the above code it is generating the following URL**

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=123456789123-lkhipfqkk6g224bnf7n9sfdsdfsdss.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.settings.basic&access_type=offline&response_type=code

> **It is pointing to 8080 inspite specifying 3000 as redirection port**
>
> **2) I am unable to generate dynamic URL which should be unique for every web request**

Pls suggest the way forward

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect uri you are sending from `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080` must exactly match one of the redirect uris you have added in google developer console.

The error message tells you exactly which uri your application is sending as its redirect uri.  You just need to add that.

> It is pointing to 8080 in spite specifying 3000 as redirection port

You only specified in Google developer console that you **will** be sending from 3000 but your application appears to be sending from 8080.

Solution: add `http://localhost:8080` to google developer console as a valid redirect uri or change your application to be sending from `http://localhost:3000` which you have added to google developer console.

Comment: In Google dev console i already set "Authorised redirect URIs"  as 3000 and in the code also nowhere i mentioned as 8080.

Comment: Again its your application and the library you are using which is configured to send from port 8080.  You could humor me and add it and then see that after working with this system for ten years i actually do know what i am talking about.  Then you can either leave it set at that or look up how to fix your application so that it runs on port 3000 instead of 8080.  Its your choice really i'm just trying to help.

Comment: I'll do it and can help me how to generate Unique ID for every request

Comment: Nope i suggest you open another question for that, as its not related to the error message you are getting from Google which you posted in this question.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo , you were right the app to pointing to default port 8080. the below line made the change                                                                                               (flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=['--auth_host_port=3000'])